# How to display member request Information from DB when clicking a link

Tags: php, sql, database, mysqli, notifications

I have a notification page. Here's my notification code:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "testdb";
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM notification ORDER BY date desc";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
?>
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr style="background-color: #eee">
        <th width="20%">Activity</th>
        <th width="40%">Description</th>
        <th width="20%">Date</th>
        <th width="20%">Action</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
     <tbody>
    <?php
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            // output data of each row
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    echo '<tr>';
                    echo '<td width="20%">'.$row['activity'].'</td>';
                    echo '<td width="40%">'.$row['description'].'</td>';
                    echo '<td width="20%">'.$row['date'].'</td>'; 
                    ?>
                    <td><a href="/test/admin/requests.php?view_id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" >VIEW</a></td>
                    <?php echo '</tr>';

        }
                  //  echo '<td width="20%">'.$row['date'].'</td>';
                  //  echo '</tr>';
        }
         else {
            echo "You have no notifications yet";
        }
        $conn->close();

        $conn=mysql_connect("localhost", "root");
        mysql_select_db("testdb", $conn);
        if (! $conn){
            DIE('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }
        $query="UPDATE notification set status ='read'";
        $retval = mysql_query( $query, $conn );

    ?>  
    </tbody>

</table>
```

Output:
[image: Output]

The code behind that VIEW link is:

```
<td><a href="/test/admin/requests.php?view_id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" >VIEW</a></td>
```

Now, for instance I click the VIEW link in of the "NEW MEMBERSHIP REQUEST" (refer to the photo please), the URL will lead me to that link and it should the information that I need to view or display for that certain member. And that's where my problem is because whenever I click the click, the information don't show up on the page, but the URL gives the correct ID number of that member..

This code is the page where the information of that certain member should appear when ever I click the link. But it display nothing but the correct id number. Help me please.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "testdb";


// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
    $id=$_GET['id'];

    $sql = ("SELECT * FROM requests where id = ".$id);
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

?>  
<?php echo  $id ?>

<br/>Name: <?php echo $row['name'] ?>
<br/>Age: <?php echo $row['age'] ?>
<br/>Date of Birth: <?php echo $row['dob'] ?>
<br/>Occupation: <?php echo $row['occupation'] ?>


<?php
}
?>
```

The name, age, date of birth and occupation are examples of the data that I'm saying which doesn't show up. But there was no error. Please please I wish someone could help me out.

ADDITIONAL:

> My notification table has 6 fields:
>
> id, user, activity, desc, status, date
>
> Requests table has 5 fields:
>   id, name, occupation, dob, age

When the user submits his membership form, the details he had input like name, occupation, dob, and age will be inserted **requests** table and at the same time it will notify the admin though the notification table/page. Now when I click that link, the ID that shows is the ID from the notification and not from the requests where his datas were stored. So I guess that's where my mistake is. And I just realized that. Hope you can still help me figure out how to get that id from the requests table. I hope I explained my problem well. I understand if you guys didn't understand it. Thank you for those who helped and for those who will help me. :)

Comment: *"I hope you already figured out what my problem is"* - lol, give us time to read it first ;-)

Comment: You're mixing `mysql_` in with `mysqli_`, *why?* That won't work.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I thought it doesn't matter. And i don't understand or do not know how to use some statement, query, etc of mysqli. Gosh i thought it's fine. So st*p*d. Sorry, my mistake. But if ever I'll change the mysql to mysqli, do you think it will work already? @Fred-ii-

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "testdb";


// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
    $id=$_GET['id'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM requests where id ='$id' ";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

?>  
<?php echo  $id ?>

<br/>Name: <?php echo $row['name'] ?>
<br/>Age: <?php echo $row['age'] ?>
<br/>Date of Birth: <?php echo $row['dob'] ?>
<br/>Occupation: <?php echo $row['occupation'] ?>


<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: I already did this while ago but still the same :( @DevMan thanks for replying tho :)

Comment: @louie than maybe editing your question would be great. :)

Comment: that is already my question, why does it not show when the code is right. Maybe I missed something idk, I'm still trying to figure it out too. Been working on this notification thing for like 3 days now and I can't move on. I'm stuck in this. I don't know how to rephrase my question, but I believe what I asked is what I really wanted to ask (and know) . :)

Comment: That shouldn't matter. MySQL will compensate for that. What would really matter is if their column is indeed an int. If it were varchar for example, then quoting would be required.

Comment: @louie are you sure that you're getting a row back from the query? Please try : echo mysqli_num_rows($result);

Comment: Which column are you referring to? @Fred-ii-

Comment: @louie he means the id column.

Comment: Did ` echo mysqli_num_rows($result);` BUT No results still. So maybe that's where the mistake is??? @DevMan

Comment: Yes I'm sure that it is an int. @Fred-ii-

Comment: @louie I write an answer to this and if it doesn't work than you have mistakes in your connection parameters.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I hope I can still ask further questions if I have one. Also, I will update my question because there's an important thing I didn't explain there. Hope you can check it out when I'm done :). Thank you so much @DevMan

Comment: I already updated my question. Please check the last part of it. Thank you guys! @DevMan

Comment: Updated my question. Thank you @Fred-ii-

Answer (score -1):

You are mixing OOP with procedural method. Use either one of them. If you are using OOP then don't use this:

```
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

It should be

```
$row=$result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Comment: I did what you said but results still don't display. :( thanks for helping tho.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with mixing those. The manual even says it's ok, not recommended but it still works.